# Write a header row into a Excel based on an Oracle query

Tags: python, excel, oracle, python-2.7, cx-oracle

I am trying to figure out an efficient way of writing a header row into a xls file from my Oracle table instead of having to do this every time, because some of my results are 50-70 columns across.

```
headings1 = ['Column 1', 'Column 2', etc]  
rowx = 0
for colx, value in enumerate(headings1):
    sheet1.write(rowx,colx,value)
```

My current code will only write the rows of data starting at row 2 because I have been manually creating an Excel file template that have all sheet names and header rows predefined, but it is a lot of work to create the template and I want to get rid of that part and have it automatically write Row 1 as my headers.

```
Import CX_Oracle
Import xlwt
Import xlutils.copy
Import xlrd    

SQL = "SELECT Column1, Column2, etc from TABLE" 
cursor = con.cursor()
cursor.execute(SQL)
wb_read = xlrd.open_workbook('Template.xls',formatting_info=True)
wb_read.Visible = 1
wb_write = copy(wb_read)
sheet0 = wb_write.get_sheet(0)

for i, row in enumerate(cursor):
    for j, col in enumerate(row):
        sheet1.write(i+1,j,col)  #Starts pasting the data at row 2
book.save('Output.xls')
```

The current file includes 5-7 sheets that I have to write data to in the same workbook as well as 5-7 cursors being used, this is an example of the first cursor.

Answer (score 1):

PEP 249 allows for a [`.description` attribute of cursor objects](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#description), which has been [implemented in cx_Oracle](http://cx-oracle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cursor.html#Cursor.description).

This returns a list, of tuples in which the first element of each tuple is the column name:

```py
>>> db = cx_Oracle.connect('schema/pw@db/db')
>>> curs = db.cursor()
>>> sql = "select * from dual"
>>> curs.execute(sql)
<__builtin__.OracleCursor on <cx_Oracle.Connection to schema@db/db>>
>>> column_names = curs.description
>>> column_names
[('DUMMY', <type 'cx_Oracle.STRING'>, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1)]
>>>
```

To demonstrate a (very) slightly more complicated situation I created this table:

```sql
SQL> create table tmp_test (col1 number, col2 varchar2(10));

Table created.
```

It's then up to you how you use it:

```py
>>> sql = "select * from tmp_test"
>>> curs.execute(sql)
<__builtin__.OracleCursor on <cx_Oracle.Connection to schema@db/db>>
>>> curs.description
[('COL1', <type 'cx_Oracle.NUMBER'>, 127, 22, 0, -127, 1), ('COL2', <type 'cx_Oracle.STRING'>, 10, 1
0, 0, 0, 1)]
>>> ','.join(c[0] for c in curs.description)
'COL1,COL2'
>>>
```

Just write this line before you start enumerating your cursor values.

Comment: Thanks Ben for you input.  I have been doing like you suggested with researching PEP249, but I still haven't been able to figure out the proper code that will put the curs.description into each column for first row in my csv file.  Do you know how to write that?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do exactly the same thing.  It was acheived the with following code:

```
# Write header row
for c, col in enumerate(cursor.description):
    ws.write(0, c, col[0])
```

Then I wrote the data records using a simular for loop that you're already using.